# XGBoost Spark Example

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xgboost

I am trying to run the XGBoost spark example.

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/jvm-packages

I am encountering a type mismatch problem at the following step.

```
val model = XGBoost.train(trainData3, paramMap, round=2, nWorkers=2, useExternalMemory=true, missing=0.0f )
```

error: type mismatch
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint]
required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint]

It seems that val trainData3 = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, inputTrainPath) earlier produces a mllib.regression.LabeledPoint rather than a ml.feature.LabelPoint that XGBoost expects.

To test my overall setup, I manually created a ml.feature.LabelPoint via

```
val trainRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(
     |   LabeledPoint(1.0, new DenseVector(Array(2.0, 3.0, 4.0))),
     |   LabeledPoint(0.0, new DenseVector(Array(5.0, 5.0, 5.0))),
     ...
     ),4)
```

This as input to xgboost.train runs without any issues.  trainRDD is a org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint

Any thoughts on why I am seeing this type mismatch?  thanks!

scala version - 2.10.6,
spark - 2.11-2.0.0,
xgboost - 0.7,
Mac OS El-Capitan

Comment: Use SparkWithRDD to convert to ml.feature.LabeledPoint type required by XGBoost.  An example can be found at https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/jvm-packages/xgboost4j-example/src/main/scala/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/scala/example/spark/SparkWithRDD.scala